# How to initialize with multiple return values in c++(0x)

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, tuples

`tuple` in boost and TR1/c++0x provides a convenient (for the writer of the function) method to return two values from a function--however it seems to damage one major feature of the language for the caller: the ability to simply use the function to initialize a variable:

```
T happy();
const auto meaningful_name(happy()); // RVO means no excess copies
```

but for:

```
tuple<T,U> sad();
```

we either have to surrender the ability to pick a meaningful name for our return values, and use `get<n>()` everywhere:

```
const auto two_unrelated_things(sad());
```

or make a temporary:

```
const auto unwanted_named_temporary(sad());
const auto one_name(get<0>(unwanted_named_temporary));
const auto two_name(get<1>(unwanted_named_temporary));
```

or switch from initialization to assignment, which only works when the types are assignable, and breaks `auto`:

```
tuple_element<0, decltype(sad())>::type one_mutable; // there might be a less
tuple_element<1, decltype(sad())>::type two_mutable; // verbose way
tie(one_mutable,two_mutable) = sad();
```

or do something unnatural to a local class:

```
const struct ugh { 
  ugh( decltype(sad()) rhs ) : one_name(get<0>(rhs)), two_name(get<1>(rhs)) {}
  const tuple_element<0, decltype(sad())>::type one_name;
  const tuple_element<1, decltype(sad())>::type two_name;
} stuff(sad()); // at least we avoid the temporary and get initialization
```

Is there a better way? I'm using VC10 compatible constructs above, would anything in full c++0x or boost help?

Ideally it would:

- allow me to use initialization, not just assignment
- let the **caller** pick the names for the returned-into variables
- not make extra copies
- work for both stack variables and class members
- possibly be a big crazy template library, but have sane syntax for caller and function writer

Comment: Interesting question, although I don't see how you could define variables of different types in a single expression. - I think "or make a temporary" option might be OK, if you change the named variables into references (avoiding copying).

Comment: Good point about the references -- I think that's a solution for stack variables.

I tried doing the same in a class:

    class C {
    public:
      C() sr(sad()), one(get<0>(sr)), two(get<1>(sr)) {}
      const T& one;
      const U& two;
    private:
      tuple<T,U> sr;
    }

But it looks like in VC10, C is two pointers bigger than the tuple, not a huge deal but kind of lame -- wouldn't it be legal for the compiler to recognize that the references are aliases and not allocate space in the instance for them?  Isn't that why pointers to references are illegal in the first place?

Comment: With a class, if the data is stored as a tuple, you could just provide named accessor methods, that call the respective `get<X>`. I doubt that there's going to be a "crazy template" based solution, because the core language simply doesn't seem to be supporting what you are asking for. Perhaps you could just reduce the number of characters you have to type with macros...

Comment: I somehow missed the comments when drafting my answer.  Once noticed, I expanded on my answer, just to again write the same thing you already had.  Go me, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::tuple<Type1, Type2> returnValue = sad();
Type1& first = std::get<0>(returnValue);
Type2& second = std::get<1>(returnValue);
```

I'm not sure what your fourth bullet means, but that satisfies all the rest.

*edit: Based on your comment above, I figured out what you meant by the fourth bullet.

```
struct Object {
    Object(const std::tuple<Type1, Type2>& t) : value(t) { }
    Type1& First() { return std::get<0>(value); }
    Type2& second() { return std::get<1>(value); }
private:
    std::tuple<Type1, Type2> value;
}
```

Modify as needed.

You could also just not use `std::tuple` at all if the returned values are so unrelated that you have to split them up in order for them to be used reasonably.  People have gotten by for years returned `struct`s with reasonably named fields, or by accepting reference parameters for output.

As an aside, you seem to be in love with `auto`.  Don't be.  Its a great feature, but this is *not* the way it should to be used.  Your code is going to end up illegible if you don't specify types from time to time.

Comment: As I think about the "class member" bit, is this even a situation where you can elide all the copies?  I think you're going to end up copying `value` at least once under any circumstances, which will obviously require copying its members at least once.  So you probably might as well just store the values directly and forget about storing the tuple at all.

Comment: I agree with not using `std::tuple` when it isn't appropriate -- I'm just worried that it'll become idiomatic and make code less understandable and full of `get<n>(sometuple)`

That said, it looks like I worry too much about extra copies: `tie(a,b) = sad()` in a constructor successfully elides all the copies of the tuple members when sad() does `return make_tuple(...)`.  

Maybe the lesson is "`const` data members are a hassle".

Comment: @bcoates: Regarding mis- and overuse of tuple. Standard library is a bit guilty itself when it represents ranges as `pair<iterator, iterator>`. OTOH, boost is employing a superior alternative: `iterator_range<iterator>` with a `begin()` and `end()` method. A range is not an abstract pair, `first` and `second` do have a concrete meaning! - I don't think one should go very tuple-happy in non-generic code.